# Contractible neighbourhood of $D^2$

Tags: general-topology

I am proving that $D^2$ is not a topological manifold, but I am running into the following. Consider $D^2\subset \mathbb{C}$ and let $1\in D^2$ and $U$ is a contractible open neighbourhood of 1. How can I show that $U\setminus\{1\}$ is still contractible?

Comment: I get what you're aiming at. However there's an alternative road. If we can always choose $U$ to be an open ball around $1$ then we're done. That's because open $B$ ball in $D^2$ around $1$ is convex and in this particular case $B\backslash\{1\}$ remains convex (by the simple algebraic argument). This however depends on the fact that we can always choose $U$ as an open ball (or at least a convex subset). Which I'm not sure about and I've created a separate question for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120035/metric-topological-manifold-and-the-choice-of-neighbourhood

Comment: I see what you mean. My question would be solved if i could choose $U$ to be convex, but I don't see why I can

Comment: Yeah, have a look at the question I've posted. Someone answered it positively (and I think it is correct). That should solve your problem.

Comment: So, for a metric topology, the definition of manifold is equivalent with "for every $m\in M$ there exists an open ball containing $m$ homeomorphoc to an open subset of $R^n$?

Comment: To an open **connected** subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Yes, it seems so.

Comment: Thank you for asking this

Comment: Apparently, **connected** subset is something we cannot achieve. I deleted my answer on the other question and posted a correction, sorry for the wrong claim.

Comment: Right, so @James I'm sorry but my idea is a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to show that *manifolds with boundary* are no *manifolds*. To do this you have to show that a boundary point does not have any open neigborhood which is homeomorphic to an open subset of the model space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

A boundary point $x$ of a manifold $M$ is characterized by the existence of a *boundary chart at $x$* which is a homeomorphism $h : U \to V$ from an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $M$ to an open subset of the Euclidean  halfspace $\mathbb{H}^n = \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times [0,\infty)$ such that $h(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \{ 0\}$.

For an interior point $x$ we have a chart at $x$ which is a homeomorphism $h : U \to V$ from an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $M$ to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

We conclude that each interior point $x$ has a contractible open neighborhood $U$ such that $U \setminus \{ x \}$ is not contractible.

Conversely, if for any contractible open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ also $U \setminus \{ x \}$ is contractible, then $x$ cannot be an interior point.

So let us consider a boundary point $x$ of $M$. We shall more generally prove that for any open neighborhood $W$ of $x$ the inclusion $i : W \setminus \{x\} \to W$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Choose a boundary chart $h : U \to V$ at $x$. W.lo.g. we may assume $U \subset W$. Let $y = h(x)$. Choose $r > 0$ such that $B_r(y) = \{ z \in \mathbb{H}^n \mid \lVert z - y \rVert \le r \} \subset V$. The set $B_r(y)$ is the compact upper half of a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $S_r(y) = \{ z \in \mathbb{H}^n \mid \lVert z - y \rVert = r \}$ be its boundary. $S_r(y)$ is a strong deformation retract of $B_r(y)$. To be explicit, using the notation $z = (z',s) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times [0,\infty)$, define a homotopy $H : B_r(y) \times I \to 
B_r(y), H(z,t) = (1-t)z + t(z',\sqrt{r^2-\lVert z'\rVert^2})$. This is well-defined because $B_r(y)$ is convex and $(z',\sqrt{r^2-\lVert z'\rVert^2}) \in S_r(y)$. We have $H(z,0) = z$, $H(z,1) = (z',\sqrt{r^2-\lVert z'\rVert^2}) \in S_r(y)$ and $H(z, t) = z$ for $z \in S_r(y)$. It is obviuos that $H$ restricts to a homotopy on $B_r(y) \setminus \{ y \}$ so that $S_r(y)$ is also a strong deformation retract of $B_r(y) \setminus \{ y \}$.

Hence $S = h^{-1}(S_r(y))$ is a strong deformation retract of both $B = h^{-1}(B_r(y))$ and $B'  = h^{-1}(B_r(y)B_r(y) \setminus \{ y \}) = B \setminus \{ x \}$. Extending the deformation retractions by the identity on $W \setminus B$, we obtain strong deformation retractions $r : W \to W \setminus int(B)$ and $r : W \setminus \{ x \} \to W \setminus int(B)$. This shows that $i$ is a homotopy equivalence.